# Is there a Scala-way to get the length of a number?

Tags: scala, numbers

I would like to know, if there is a Scala built-in method to get the length of the decimal representation of an integer ?

Example: `45` has length `2`; `10321` has length `5`.

One could get the length with `10321.toString.length`, but this smells a bit because of the overhead when creating a String object. Is there a nicer way or a built-in method ?

UPDATE:

- With 'nicer' I mean a faster solution
- I am only interested in positive integers

Comment: It isn't clear without ambiguity what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you only interested in unsigned integers? Should the length of negative numbers include the `-`?

Comment: numbers don't have a length IMHO, they only have a value. Strings have length so converting to string and getting the length seems about right. what do you need the length for?

Comment: @aishwarya the expression 'length' is meant as a shortcut for 'the highest used index position (+ 1) in the decimal representation of the number', see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system#Positional_systems_in_detail

Comment: Completely unscientific REPL benchmark: `math.log10(n).toInt + 1` is about 20% faster than `n.toString.length` for the first billion natural numbers.

Comment: @TravisBrown: yes, but if you need to print these numbers, you will need to convert them to a String soon or later...

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely personal preference, but I think the logarithm method looks nicer without a branch. For positive values only, the `abs` can be omitted of course.

```
def digits(x: Int) = {
    import math._
    ceil(log(abs(x)+1)/log(10)).toInt
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`toString` then get `length` of int will not work for negative integers. This code will work not only for positive numbers but also negatives.

```
def digits(n:Int) = if (n==0) 1 else math.log10(math.abs(n)).toInt + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want speed then something like the following is pretty good, assuming random distribution:

```
def lengthBase10(x: Int) =
  if      (x >= 1000000000) 10
  else if (x >= 100000000)   9
  else if (x >= 10000000)    8
  else if (x >= 1000000)     7
  else if (x >= 100000)      6
  else if (x >= 10000)       5
  else if (x >= 1000)        4
  else if (x >= 100)         3
  else if (x >= 10)          2
  else                       1
```

Calculating logarithms to double precision isn't efficient if all you want is the floor.

The conventional recursive way would be:

```
def len(x: Int, i: Int = 1): Int = 
  if (x < 10) i 
  else len(x / 10, i + 1)
```

which is faster than taking logs for integers in the range 0 to 10e8.

`lengthBase10` above is about 4x faster than everything else though.

Comment: lengthBase10 can be rewritten to use binary search instead of linear search. Binary version would always take same time. (Good for real time systems.) It would be much less readable though.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the job:

```
def numericLength(n: Int): Int = BigDecimal(n).precision
```

Answer (score 2):

Take log to the base 10, take the floor and add 1.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

```
def numberLength(i : Int): Int = i.toString.length
```

You might add a guarding-condition because negative `Int` will have the length of their abs + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility can be:

```
private lazy val lengthList = (1 until 19).map(i => i -> math.pow(10, i).toLong)

def numberSize(x: Long): Int =
  if (x >= 0) positiveNumberSize(x)
  else positiveNumberSize(-x) + 1

private def positiveNumberSize(x: Long): Int =
  lengthList
    .collectFirst {
      case (l, p) if x < p => l
    }
    .getOrElse(19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people gave the most efficient answer of (int) log(number)+1
But I want to get a bit deeper into understanding why this works.

Let N be a 3 digit number. This means N can be any number between 100 and 1000, or :

100 < N < 1000
=> 10^2 < N < 10^3

The Logarithmic function is continuous , therefore :

log(10^2) < log(N) < log(10^3)
=> 2 < log(N) < 3

We can conclude that N's logarithm is a number between 2 and 3 , or in other words , any 3 digit numbers' logarithm is between 2 and 3.

So if we take only the integer part of a numbers logarithm(eg. the integer part of 2.567 is 2) and add 1 we get the digit length of the number.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

```
number.toString.toCharArray.size
```

input  -  output

```
45   -   2
100  -   3
```

Comment: The `.toString` method was covered in the question itself. This "solution" isn't.

Comment: toCharArray.size is added and it works 100% no doubt at all

Comment: `toCharArray` is a pointless addition that serves no purpose. It works 100% but it's **not** what the question asked for.